# How to keep MySQL general_log after I restart my computer?

Tags: mysql, logs

I use a statement `set global general_log = 'ON'` to enable the general_log on my computer.

After I restart or shutdown it, I have to run the statement again.

How can I config MySQL write general log without to run the statement again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to my.ini

```
[mysqld]
log
```

If you have a specfic place for the log, such as C:\mysql_general.log

```
[mysqld]
log=C:/mysql_general.log
log="C:\mysql_general.log"
```

It's one of those. I haven't done mysql in Windows in a while.

Then restart mysql

```
net start mysql
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

Prior to MySQL 5.6, you can use [**log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log).

In MySQL 5.6, log is deprecated. Use general-log instead.

### **UPDATE 2011-12-09 22:18 EDT**

If you do not have my.ini defined, then you must define one.

To keep things simple, just create my.ini in the folder where my-huge.ini, my-large.ini, my-medium.ini, and my-small.ini appear. Just open up notepad on my.ini in that folder.

Then add the lines I mentioned before:

```
[mysqld]
log
```

or

```
[mysqld]
log=C:/mysql_general.log
log="C:\mysql_general.log"
```

### **UPDATE 2011-12-09 22:26 EDT**

In the worst case, try putting my.ini in C:\

Comment: Execuse me, but I have my-huge.ini, my-large.ini, my-medium.ini, my-small.ini. Which one is the approriate ini? I use xampp for php mysql and apache.