# What is running right now?

Tags: mysql, logs, scripting

I know I can use "show processlist" to see what is running when I'm in the office. How can I see what is running when I'm not there.

Something is running on my server at 3am every morning that is generating a IO Rate Alert and a CPU Usage Alert, but I don't know what it is. Is there a logging system that I should be using or a script I can write that will report what is currently running against the database at that time.

The alerts come in within the same rough time-frame every night, about 0300 - 0330.

I'm not even sure if this is a DBA question or more a Sys Admin question?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you running MySQL ?

Comment: Yes. MySQL 5.5.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three(3) options to go about looking at what is running in MySQL

## OPTION #1 : General Log

You could simply activate the general log and look for the timestamp between 3:00-3:30 AM. You could either have the general log as a text file or a MyISAM table. Here are my posts on using the general log:

- [How to enable MySQL general log?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/how-to-enable-mysql-general-log/10346#10346) (Jan 08, 2012)
- [How to keep MySQL general_log after I restart my computer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9012/how-to-keep-mysql-general-log-after-i-restart-my-computer?rq=1) (Dec 10, 2011)
- [How do I output MySQL logs to syslog?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/how-do-i-output-mysql-logs-to-syslog/3571#3571) (Jun 30, 2011)

## OPTION #2 : Slow Log

Same setup procedure as the General Log. Here are my past posts on this:

- [MySQL slow log configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/mysql-slow-log-configuration/15890#15890) (Mar 30, 2012)
- [Create a custom log table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/create-a-custom-log-table-in-mysql/8117#8117) (Nov 18, 2011)

## OPTION #3 : Query Digest

The problem with Options 1 and 2 is that they record only completed queries. If you are trying to catch long running queries in the act of running long between 3:00-3:30AM, *even before they get recorded in the slow log or general log*, you have to go with setting up a crontab.

I usually use MAATKIT's [**mk-query-digest**](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) (most prefer the most current [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html)). Here are my posts on how to script a crontabed Query Digest:

- [Investigate peak in MySQL throughput](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16950/investigate-peak-in-mysql-throughput/16964#16964) (Apr 24, 2012)
- [MySQL general query log performance effects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/mysql-general-query-log-performance-effects/8382#8382) (Nov 24, 2011)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* home brew a bash script to fire off and log the info. Something like:

```
#/bin/bash
USER=monuser
PASS=monpassword
LOGFILE=/path/to/info.log

for i in {1..25}; do 
   mysql -u $USER -p$PASS -h localhost -e "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G" >> $LOGFILE ;
   sleep 1 ; 
done
```

Then just set a **crontab** to fire off the script say, every 3 min when the hour is 2 or 3am.

```
*/3 2,3 * * * /path/to/script.sh 2>&1
```